# How can I make a Perl regex more readable?

Tags: regex, perl

I have an array filled with database fieldnames which I run a grep command over to remove fields that are not desired.  Looks ugly in code but it is very useful because we can easily see what fields in the database we are not passing to another program.  The grep command does not like my carriage returns and ignores the field immediately after the CR.  There are a lot of ugly ways I can think to fix this and also many complicated ways I saw on google but isn't there a way to ignore the CRs within the greps "//"?  I really appreciate you guys taking a look at this.

```
@fieldNames = grep ! /dbid|history|RecordID|CCObjects|MergeSWCRs|AssociatedIntegrationSet|Level1TestResults|
                     Level2TestResults|Level3TestResults|Level4TestResults|Reviews|WithdrawCR|
                     AssociatedWithdrawnCR|Attachments|AssociatedPRs|OriginatingSolution|AssociatedSWRsFull|
                     AssociatedSWRsDelta|ClonedFrom|ClonedTo|AssociatedComment|ExternalLinks|ratl_mastership/, @fieldNames;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`/x` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%2Fx) to make your regex more readable and ignore whitespace.

I.e.:

```
@fieldNames = grep !
    /dbid|history|RecordID|CCObjects|MergeSWCRs|AssociatedIntegrationSet|Level1TestResults|
    Level2TestResults|Level3TestResults|Level4TestResults|Reviews|WithdrawCR|
    AssociatedWithdrawnCR|Attachments|AssociatedPRs|OriginatingSolution|AssociatedSWRsFull|
    AssociatedSWRsDelta|ClonedFrom|ClonedTo|AssociatedComment|ExternalLinks|ratl_mastership/x,
    @fieldNames;
```

Or perhaps slightly optimised:

```
my @fieldNames =
    grep ! /
        dbid|
        history|
        RecordID|
        CCObjects|
        MergeSWCRs|
        Level[1-4]TestResults|
        Reviews|
        WithdrawCR|
        Associated(?:WithdrawnCR|PRs|SWRsFull|SWRsDelta|Comment|IntegrationSet)|
        Attachments|
        OriginatingSolution|
        Cloned(?:From|To)|
        ExternalLinks|
        ratl_mastership
    /x,
    @fieldNames;
```

Comment: You're kidding me.  An "x"?  I just tried it and it worked perfectly.  I'm going to read that whole link that you posted.  Thank you very much.  That is sooo cool!

Comment: @Matt... if you're researching regexes, http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html is definitely worth a read.

Comment: Thank you stevieb.  Appreciate the link...I'm looking though it now.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a regular expression:

```
my %ignored = (
    dbid      => 1,
    history   => 1,
    RecordID  => 1,
    CCObjects => 1,
    # ...
);

# or define the hash this way, if you prefer
# my %ignored = map { $_ => 1 } qw(dbid history RecordID CCObjects ...);

@fieldNames = grep { !$ignored{$_} } @fieldNames;
```

Comment: Matt J, this is awesome thank you.  But why don't you like a regular expression for what I am doing?  I'm seriously asking as I'm new to PERL.  The regular expression I was using accomplishes the same thing with fewer more readable lines.  But this might be faster....Im going to time it now.  Thank you so much for answering my question.  I wish I had one ounce of your brain power.

Comment: I love regular expressions, but I only like to use them when I need to. Perl programmers have a tendency to use regular expressions for everything, but sometimes all you need is a simple string match (which should be a few microseconds faster, too).

Comment: That makes sense and I'm close to having my code changed to try it.  Really appreciate your advice and knowledge.

Comment: Regular expressions are basically a programming language in their own right. They're _built_ for search/replace type operations, and whilst you can do LOTs more than that - you end up with some really hard to follow code.